# Ajax Response ReadyState Jumps To 4

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, google-chrome-extension

I'm building a chrome extension and my Ajax request's response comes off as "ready" (Status 200 and readystate 4) 4 times instead of just once , and it doesn't go through stages 1-3 . Instead 4 times 4 . This is bad for me since I'm alerting something to the user 4 times instead of once .

My code is simple javascript

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    console.log(xmlhttp.readyState + xmlhttp.status);
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        if (xmlhttp.response) checkForAlertTab(xmlhttp.response);
        else console.log('false');
    }
}
xmlhttp.open("POST", "http://myserver.php", true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
xmlhttp.send(sendToServer);
```

My code in the server is just a php that pulls some data from a database and echos it back out , the response is nice and dandy (the information is there) but why isn't the ajax readystate going through his stages normally - what can be the cause of this ?

Answer (score -1):

Why not use jQuery in your chrome extension and use $.ajax! It's lightweight and lets you do stuff easily.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Anyway, possible reason for above issue -- since your xmlhttp object is global, maybe chrome assigns a new onreadystatechange each time you call ajax post instead of replacing it. It depends on the number of calls really.

Comment: It's not global , there's a function wrapping everything . jQuery isn't the answer for everything though I just might try posting with it and check if I see a different result . I still want to understand how this can happen...

Comment: is your code within some loop or an event callback which fires multiple times?

Comment: -1 because it does not answer the question at all. If you improve the answer, I'll gladly retract my downvote. If you don't know how to improve it, I suggest to delete the answer.

Comment: Please post a better answer if you have one!